# React Native : this.push is not a function onLeftButtonPress

Tags: ios, react-native

... but is onRightButtonPress()

On the following picture, clicking on the right button works fine but clicking on the left button throws this error :

[image: main view of the application]

[image: error thrown when clicking on the left button "Filtrer"]

Here is the code where the error is thrown :

```
    class Restaurants extends Page {
        static route() {
            return {
                component: Restaurants,
                title: 'Carte',
                leftButtonTitle: 'Filtrer',
                onLeftButtonPress() {
                    this.push(Liste.route());
                },
                rightButtonTitle: 'Liste',
                onRightButtonPress() {
                    this.push(Liste.route());
                }
            };
        }

    // More code here ...

    }
```

Comment: have you tried binding `this`? maybe you are losing context.

Comment: do you mean changing the function to this ?
        `onLeftButtonPress() {
     this.push(Liste.route()).bind(this);
        }`

Comment: I'm not sure that would work because you'd just be binding whatever context you're in when the function `onRightButtonPress` is called.

Comment: I don't see how you would do it then.. If you've got any suggestions, it'd be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try using es6 fat arrow

```
class Restaurants extends Page {
  static route() {
    return {
      component: Restaurants,
      title: 'Carte',
      leftButtonTitle: 'Filtrer',
      onLeftButtonPress: () => { 
        this.push(Liste.route());
      },
      rightButtonTitle: 'Liste',
      onRightButtonPress() {
        this.push(Liste.route());
      }
    };
  }

  // More code here ...

}
```

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work with es6 fat arrow .. It throws this error : `_this3.push is not a function`